# symfony 2 save data

Tags: symfony, save, doctrine-orm

A quick question about saving data in symfony 2. I have this method (just for testing):

```
protected function createProduct()
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName('My product');
    $product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet');
    $product->setIsPublished(1);
    $product->setPosition(1);


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Then i have the action (just for testing also):

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->createCategory();
    ...
    render ...
}
```

My problem is that when i execut the index action, the product is save twice in my database. Does anyone had similar problems ? Any way to solve it ?

Update: - full controller test class:

```
namespace Test\CategoryBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Test\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function createAction()
    {
        $c = new Category();
        $c->setName('Category');
        $c->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet');
        $c->setIsPublished(1);
        $c->setPosition(1);


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($c);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('Created category id '.$c->getId());

    }

}
```

Routing in src/Test/CategoryBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:

```
TestCategoryBundle_create:
    pattern:  /category/create
    defaults: { _controller: TestCategoryBundle:Category:create }
```

Routing in app/config/routing.yml:

```
TestCategoryBundle:
    resource: "@TestCategoryBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Comment: The code you have posted should not behave this way. The problem should be outside of this code. Maybe your `createProduct` is called elsewhere or `indexAction` is called twice?

Comment: I was searching for a duplicate, but i don't have it. This is the only method in controller. Anyway, if i use the fixtures bundle, the data is inserted correctly. This is my full controller class:

Comment: Is this a result of you running the page twice?  The controller looks like it should add only one entity to the database.

Comment: No Chris. The routing is OK, the page is accessed only once, etc. I am sure that is something related to the code, because i am testing this on 3 different systems. Maybe someone can think at some code related issue that can affect this ? (With MongoDB has the same problem, and this was since symfony v 2.0.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I don't know yet if it's normal, but at least the data is not duplicated anymore.

The problem was solved by adding redirection to the createAction method. If you are not using a redirect, the data is duplicated. It's normal ??? Anyway, this is the solution that worked for me.

```
public function createAction()
{
    $c = new Category();
    $c->setName('My Category');
    $c->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet');
    $c->setIsPublished(1);
    $c->setPosition(1);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($c);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your_routing_name_to_redirect'));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a solution for me. I have the same problem and can't find the reason. I tried this on a simple controller and write error to log. After I visit page I have TWO entries in log, but profiler shows only ONE entry. But in fact it's two

Comment: I don't know WTF but this bug is only on my machine (Mac OS) and on the dev server (unix) it's ok

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in Symfony 1.4.

I found a

```
<img src="">
```

(without src atributte), It causes the page load itself. Its not a symfony problem, its a browser feature :P

Maybe you have one too.